# I have to switch between my laptop and desktop a lot. How can I share the git changes without committing them all?

Tags: git, github, vpn, fileserver

Due to medical issues I am on my back a lot and have to program from a laptop. I prefer programming on my desktop, but I am forced to bed due to pain quite often. What I want to do is setup a file server on my local network. Deploy my git repository to it and work on it from there. In theory if I were to move from desktop to laptop, I'd be using the same files so all my Changes should move without forcing a commit. I use GitHub desktop to manage my gits so I will need to configure that as well.

Does anyone know how to set this up on an M1 mac? If not, I can use a Windows 11 desktop to host.

Comment: The easiest way would be to set up a NAS Drive.  They are cheap these days and you can put it on your network. Your repo will be on the NAS and you can share with all your computers.   Other option is to have your laptop or desktop run as a share and access from other computers.  The benefit of NAS is that your pc does not need to be on and can be set up to access remotely.

Comment: This is a very good idea. Thanks for sharing.